# iOS device token for push notification inside brackets or not

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

When I do NSLog on my `deviceToken`, the string is printed within brackets as `"<0000 ... 0000>"`. But all the online tutorials show the numbers/string without any brackets `< ... >`. So should I remove the brackets when saving the deviceToken? And yes, they do get save on my server presently with the brackets. And if I am to remove the brackets, what's the code for doing so?

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application
 didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
    NSString* deviceTokenString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",deviceToken];    
    NSLog(@"Device token is %@",deviceTokenString);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken  {
    NSString * deviceTokenString = [[deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    deviceTokenString = [deviceTokenString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    NSLog(@"content---%@", deviceTokenString);
}
```

this is another choice

```
NSString * deviceTokenString = [[[[deviceToken description] 
                        stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<"withString:@""] 
                       stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""] 
                      stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];


NSLog(@"device token - %@", deviceTokenString);
```

Comment: much appreciated. Accepting soon

Comment: have a happy day brother